# Error during installing filament 3.2 to laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel-10, laravel-filament

i was installing laravel 10 after installation when in tried to install filament from the command given by https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/installation. but its giving an error. the error message is shared below.

[image: error message]

here's my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.5",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
            "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
            "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

i tried adding recommended version filament technically its not available in their filament documentation.

Comment: Seems like their is composer package dont line up prob cause dependecies. you can try to do composer require with --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the composer require inside laravel project dir ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to run `composer require filament/filament:"^3.2.52" -W`.
this works and filament installs sucessfully without any error issue and compatible for laravel 11.